# Performing LIKE query in Sqlite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android project and I need to perform a like query in SQLITE i.e.
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE %value%`.

Below is the code I am using to try and build up the query.

```
myDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            String[] columns = new String[]{"*"};
            if (searchType == SearchType.App)
            {
                where = "appName like ?";
            }
            else if (searchType == SearchType.Username)
            {
                where = "username like ?";
            }
            else if (searchType == SearchType.Name)
            {
                where = "company like ?";
            }

            String[] args = {"%" + searchTerm + "%"};
            cursor = myDB.query("password", columns, where, args, null, null, null);
```

For some reason this doesn't return any results if I try and search for a pattere but If I search for the whole string it finds something. For example, if I have the value Hello World and perform a search for Hello, nothing comes back, if I do a search for Hello World then I get a result.

I can't see why this wouldn't work. I've tried adding and removing the `%` symbols from around the search term but didn't make any difference.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
I've tried what dymmeh said but this doesn't seem to have worked. Below is the code I have tried.

```
myDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            String[] columns = new String[]{"*"};
            if (searchType == SearchType.App)
            {
                where = "appName like %" + searchTerm + "%";
            }
            else if (searchType == SearchType.Username)
            {
                where = "username like %" + searchTerm + "%";
            }
            else if (searchType == SearchType.Name)
            {
                where = "company like %" + searchTerm + "%";
            }

            //String[] args = {"%" + searchTerm + "%"};
            cursor = myDB.query("password", columns, where, null, null, null, null);
```

Using the code above now crashes the app, I've tried surrounding the the % searchTerm % in single quote marks, and this stops the app crashing but I get the original problem that if I search for the exact string, a result is found if I search for part of the string, I don't get any results.

Comment: Your first method is preferred and should work fine, I'm guessing the `searchTerm` isn't what you think it is. For the record `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%value%'` (with single or double quotes) is the correct syntax as you discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the select arguments when using `like`..

Instead just do

```
where = "appName like '%" + searchTerm + "%'";
```

And just pass `null` for your `args`

Comment: Thanks this did work, I only did on one of the IF statements for testing but did it on the wrong one. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sqlite that well, but I'm pretty sure that when you are using a prepared statement in the way you are it's interpreting the %'s as being part of the query string.

You might want to try something like

```
select * from myTable where myField like concat('%', ?, '%')
```

But I have no idea if it would work.